# explode() в массиве.

Tags: php

`explode` возвращает массив. Как заставить работать `explode` внутри массива?

Листинг `file.dat` примерно таков:

```
string=8:1
string=15:1
string=26:1
string=30:10
string=18:10
string=2:10
```

Читаем файл `file.dat`:

```
$dat = file('file.dat');
$dat = str_replace(":", "=", $dat);
// где то тут всаживаем explode();
$count = count($dat);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $dat[$i] . '<br />';
    // string=8:1 нужно получить как [0] [1] [2]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то как-то так...

```
    $data = explode("\r\n", $data);

    $dataLength = count($data);
    for($i=0; $i<$dataLength; $i++) {
        $type = explode('=',$data[$i]);
        $values = explode(':', $type[1]);

        $result[$i][0] = $type[0];
        $result[$i][1] = $values[0];
        $result[$i][2] = $values[1];
    }
    print_r($result);
//на выходе массив массивов со значениями
// 0 - string, 1 - первое число, 2 - второе
```

Comment: Т.к. в данном случае строки делятся только на две части, то для `explode()` желательно использовать 3'ий параметр `$limit`.

Answer (score 1):

Одна из многих страниц, которые я посещаю регулярно, и практически уже наизусть помню.:

[Функции для работы с массивами](http://www.php.ru/manual/ref.array.html)

Возможно, вам поможет.